# C++ Winapi Owner drawn listbox animation

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox, ownerdrawn

I've got an owner-drawn listbox, in which I would like to draw an animation of some progress. A picture of what I've got so far will say a lot I believe:

[image: Listbox]

Each file is added to the listbox when dropped on the DRAG HERE area, where a new thread is created and encryption/decryption process is started. The enc/dec process saves a progress value (in percents) to a variable given, of how much job is done.
As the progress grows by one, I'm redrawing the listbox.

```
if(progress - prevProgress > 1.0)
{
    InvalidateRect(Listbox, &ListboxProgressRect, TRUE);
    UpdateWindow(Listbox);
    prevProgress = progress;
}
```

The problem is that **each item is redrawn even when only one item ought to be redrawn.** The `ListboxProgressRect` area in fact includes the most right 40 pixels of the listbox times the listbox height.

I would like to handle the drawing entirely in WM_PAINT with subclassed Ctrl, but I don't know how would I draw the items and the scrollbar feature. *An editbox and a button next to the progress bar would be nice as well.*

**Should I subclass the listbox and handle all the drawing? If so, how can I draw the scrollbar (and make it work)?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only want to redraw one item, so you should only invalidate one item.

Trouble is, you don't know where the item is.  The listbox does.  So ask it.

Send [`LB_GETITEMRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

how many thread can handle your listbox?. i guess it is a bad idea to use theards. better you use a timer for the entire listbox that check the status of each visible element and check whether it has to be redrawn or not. use InvalidateRect to force WM_PAINT to redraw the list.

threads just complicate your code.

to avoid to handle drawing scrobars, don't subclass list, but create an onwerdrawn listbox instead, it is flexible, and handle scroll smoothing as well.

Comment: The threads are used for Encrypting/Decrypting files, so they are necessary. To the last paragraph, please, take a look at my question once again - I don't have subclassed listbox, but ownerdrawn.

Comment: OK, so exclude the threads from painting the listbox, assign them the task to only update items status . and let the timer repaint items when needed. (Use critical sections to update status of items.)

Comment: I'm repainting the listbox as few times as possible, that's why I call the `InvalidateRect` in the thread, where the encryption is running. Whenever the encryption process does 1% of it's job, it repaints the listbox. With some timer I would have to repaint it every time even when not needed.

Comment: the data  of each item should be a struct. right? add to the struct a member called let say 'Dirty'  which will be set by thread whenever state changed, the timer check every visible item if Dirty flag is set, if so it call InvalidateRect but not UpdateWindow. ON WM_DRAW reset all drawn items flag (Dirty) to 0; at the end of timer check, it can call UpdateWindow if any flag was found (set)

Comment: other possibility is just to use existing members (progress & prevProgress) to check if item is dirty or not; in WM_PAINT set prevProgress=progress  when painting is done

Comment: I don't see any point of doing this. It would still do the same, except with another code. Basicly I want to be able to redraw only one certain item.

Comment: invalidateRect just mark the area that should be repainted, it doesn't in fact redraw the item, WinProc is smart enough to know which item should be painted and generate WM_DRAWITEM  accordingly. so don't wory about that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92198/discussion-between-proxict-and-milevyo).